# Change time intervals after zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I use [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/q_dO0pRf3vA) topic to generate my custom time intervals with `dc.lineChart`.
With 5 minutes interval it looks like the next picture:

[image]

After zooming I need to change time intervals to smaller. As I understand, I need to do some re-group with new intervals, but how can I do it?

Comment: I trust you looked at [the example I sent earlier](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html). Did you try to integrate it? What happened next?

Comment: Yes, but maybe didn't understand fully. Where should I have call your `setup()` function from example if I use `.rangeChart`? Add to `onFiltered` listener?

Comment: I'd go with a listener on the [`zoomed` event](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor). It would be fantastic to include an example in dc.js for this. If you want to contribute, maybe you could start a fiddle [by forking this one](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/u57bfje8/), start with the `zoomed` listener and the code from the other example, see what breaks, and update your question?

Comment: @Gordon Hi! Check my example for dc.js [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u57bfje8/42/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current topic I used [this](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html) example and add some logic to `on.('zoomed')` chart listener. I wrote some example for other people on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u57bfje8/42/).

```
// read data
let experiments = d3.csv.parse(someCsvData);

//create and bind charts
let chart = dc.lineChart('#chart'),
    scrollChart = dc.barChart('#scrollChart');

// parse date    
experiments.forEach(x => {
  x.date = Date.parse(x.date);
});

// create crossfilter, dimension and group
let ndx   = crossfilter(experiments),
    dim   = ndx.dimension(d => new Date(d.date)),
    scrollGroup = dim.group(d3.time.month).reduceSum(d => +d.volume)

// define function for selecting time ticks
const getNormalizingTimeFunction = (dataSize) => {
    switch (true) {
        case dataSize < 100:
            return d3.time.day;
        case dataSize < 300:
            return d3.time.week;
        default:
            return d3.time.month;
    }
}

// create `start` and `end` time points
let startDate = experiments[0].date;
let endDate = experiments[experiments.length - 1].date;

scrollChart
  .width(768)
  .height(50)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, endDate]))
  .margins({left: 50, top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
  .clipPadding(10)
  .dimension(dim)
  .group(scrollGroup)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .elasticY(true)
  .yAxis().ticks(0);

chart
 .width(768)
 .height(480)
 .brushOn(false)
 .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, endDate]))
 .margins({left: 50, top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
 .rangeChart(scrollChart)
 .dimension(dim)
 .group(scrollGroup)
 .renderArea(true)
 .on('zoomed', (chart) => {
    let actions = dim.top(Infinity);
    let normalizeTime = getNormalizingTimeFunction(actions.length);
    let newGroup = dim.group(normalizeTime).reduceSum(d => +d.volume)
    chart.group(newGroup);
    chart.redraw();
 });

chart.render();
scrollChart.render();
```